# Implement CircuitHandlerService using Blazor wasm

Tags: blazor, webassembly

I am currently doing a project using Blazor wasm. I tried to implement circuithandler service but it is not working. Can anyone advise me if there a way to implement circuithandler service using blazor wasm or circuithandler service dont support blazor wasm. Thanks

Comment: Blazor circuits do apply to Blazor Server. They are not used in Blazor WASM